# Schedule Celery task for a time specified in object

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I'm working on a Django app that aggregates events from different services and performs services at the time of those events.  I store this information in an Event class.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I have a Celery task that should be run at the `start` datetime of a particular Event instance.

```
@task
def do_something():
    print "Hey it's time for that event..."
```

I thought I could use Django post-save signal to schedule `do_something` at the specified `start` datetime (or 5-60 seconds before/after is acceptable too) but I have not yet been able to figure out how to do this.

I've reviewed the options for Entries but this is not a cron job, this is a one-time occurrence.  I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do this.  I have a working solution right now actually - poll the Entries table every 60 seconds looking for Events that start within the next 60 seconds - but this seems wonky.

Comment: Have you tried something? The post-save idea seems valid.